# Python Foreach line in file shell execute a command on linux and then echo output to file

Tags: python

So I am trying to grep through my list. How would I go about doing a foreach line in file script in python then shell executing the command code below.

```
awk -F';' -v q=line '{for(i=1;i<NF;++i){if($i==q){print $(i+1);break}}}' info.csv
```

**The output of this shell execute will be the name variable, for each line/string.

The purpose of this is to search each string in my file, and to output the name and the string together in a file. The name is what is being outputting by the awk command. And essentially I need a new file (the output) with just the string,name or name,string.

Firstly, I want to load the file containing all of the strings line by line (strings.txt), then I want to Search the strings line by line (line=string each line) with that awk command and output each case line by line into the file like this

```
string,name
string,name
string,name
string,name
string,name
string,name
string,name
```

The name is the output of the awk command.

Comment: Uncertain what you mean. Could you include an example of what your input file (info.csv) looks like?

Comment: @MJB Well what the info.csv is kind of irrelevant. It is outputting a name. I.e. Tom_Celler

Comment: @MJB The info.csv file is not the file i want to input full of the strings. This is the file I want to search. Let me know if that clears things up

Comment: Ok, that change is helpful. But are you asking for python code to do this? You mention python and grep, but it seems you don't need either, so I am still confused. Are you seeking a way to do this task, using either python or grep or awk? Or am I still missing your point?

Comment: @MJB Yes either or to be honest. Just a solution to this problem. I'm trying to perform the command for each string and save every output + string line by line. I have a thousand or so of the strings.

Answer (score 1):

I hesitate to write an answer, because I am not confident I understand the goal yet, but you could do something like this just using standard bash commands:

```
for string in $(cat strings.txt); do
    grep ${string} info.csv
done > saved_output.txt
```

If your initial input file (strings.txt) is more complex, you can add a filter to the grep like this:

```
for string in $(cat strings.txt); do
    grep ${string} info.csv | awk -F\; '{printf ("%s;%s\n", $3, $4)}'
done > saved_output.txt
```

That way you only print the columns you are interested -- in this case, I guessed cols 3 and 4 are of interest to you.

If this is totally off base, tell me and I will try again.

Comment: Hi, sorry if I was unclear - The string is just each line in strings.txt (line by line). And I'm trying to execute the awk command for each line in the string. Is this what it does? Just clarifying, going to test it in a minute

Comment: I'm trying run this command for each of the lines in strings.txt, awk -F';' -v q=LINE '{for(i=1;i<NF;++i){if($i==q){print $(i+1);break}}}' info.csv (LINE being each line in string.txt, then this command will search for that string inside of info and output it. That is the goal. Does this make sense? Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Here is what info.csv looks like (this is just one entry/row/line inside so you can see the format) 2124605053;travellobby;info@travellobby.in;91;8126681266;TRAVEL LOBBY (INDIA);Flights | Hotels | Holidays | Cruises | Travel Insurance | VisaTag #travellobby for a feature.Facebook | Twitter  TravelLobby;309;149;140;http://www.travellobby.in/;Travel Company;73, Shopping Complex, Sector 7, Urban Estate;132001;29.69;76.988333333333

Comment: Ah I think you had the right idea actuially, but sadly: ./b.sh: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `}'
./b.sh: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: What shell are you using? I used bash, and it uses curly braces for variables. You might just use $string instead of ${string} in the grep line (line 2 above).